# Upgrade 20.04->22.04: restart

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, reboot

I have started upgrade my current version 20.04 to 22.04.
During the upgrade I have restarted computer (because of electricity off->on).
Then switched on the computer and it does not provide a logon screen but there is word Ubuntu and rolling progress.
Should I wait or re-install OS?

Comment: The update progress has been interrupted and probably the boot files got damaged. It's better if you just try to reinstall the OS once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*During the upgrade I have restarted computer (because of electricity off->on)*"

That's unfortunate.

During a release-upgrade is the worst possible time to lose power.

Since you cannot login....

- Make a new LiveUSB on a working system.
- Boot the LiveUSB. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to rescue your data onto some other safe media.
- Use the LiveUSB to reinstall Ubuntu.

Advanced users might be able to use a TTY to try to repair the system. Sometimes it can be repaired. Sometimes not. Repair requires appropriate skills, knowledge, and experience to repair a hopelessly mismatched package system from a chroot. This may take longer than simply reinstalling.